# String index out of range in filter function

Tags: python, list, algorithm, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of binary numbers in string format, such as this `['01100', '11001']` where all of them are the same length. I'm filtering on the condition that the numbers on the position `i` must match the number on the position `i` from a list of binary integers such as `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.

This is what I tried:

```
def name(data, gamma):
    res = data
    for i in range(0, len(gamma)):
        res = list(filter(lambda x: int(x[i]) == gamma[i], res))
    return list(res)
```

where `data` is the list of binary string and `gamma` is the list of binary integers.

It throws a `IndexError: string index out of range` even tough this works just fine:

```
def get_O2(data, gamma):
    res = data
    for i in range(0, len(gamma)):
        print(int(data[0][i]) == gamma[i])
    return list(res)
```

Comment: `name(['01100', '11001'], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1])` works for me, and return an empty list as expected

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] by including an example input which leads to the error?

Comment: Could you give a few more examples of input->output that you expect? What should be the output of `name(['01100', '11001', '10101'], [1,0,1,0,1])`?

Comment: Note that your function `name` loops with an index `i in range(len(gamma))` but index `i` is used as an index both for `gamma` and for `x`, where `x` is an element of `res`. So, you are going to get an `index out of range` error if one of the strings in `data` is too short. For instance, `name(['01'], [1,0,1,0,1])` will produce the error.

Comment: A simple way to fix that problem is to test that the length of `x` is equal to the length of `gamma` before testing the equality of the bits. For instance you could add a first `filter` before the for-loop, and filter out all the strings that don't have the appropriate length.

Comment: Filtering the ones that don't match the length works, altough I'm sure all the numbers have the same length so I have no idea why it threw an error...

Comment: Your certainty that all the strings have the same length seems to be unwarranted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your function name loops with an index `i in range(len(gamma))`, but index `i` is used as an index both for gamma and for x, where x is an element of `res`. So, you are going to get an `index out of range error` if one of the strings in `data` is too short. For instance:

```py
name(['01'], [1,0,1,0,1])
```

will produce the error.

Even worse, sometimes you won't get an error, but the result will be wrong:

```py
print( name(['1010167'], [1,0,1,0,1]) )
# ['1010167']
```

Here the string `'1010167'` should have been filtered out, but it wasn't, because its first five characters match `gamma`.

A simple way to fix that problem is to test that the length of x is equal to the length of gamma before testing the equality of the bits. For instance you could add a first filter before the for-loop, and filter out all the strings that don't have the appropriate length:

```py
def name(data, gamma):
    res = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == len(gamma), data))
    for i in range(0, len(gamma)):
        res = list(filter(lambda x: int(x[i]) == gamma[i], res))
    return list(res)

print( name(['01100', '10101', '11001', '01', '010101010101010'], [1,0,1,0,1]) )
# ['10101']
```

However, I think it is cleaner to use a single `filter`, and have this filter check everything at once.

Because the function in `filter` is going to be a bit more complicated, I suggest using a `def` rather than a `lambda`:

```py
def string_matches_intlist(x, gamma):
    return len(x) == len(gamma) and all(int(c) == b for c,b in zip(x, gamma))

def name(data, gamma):
    return list(filter(lambda x: string_matches_intlist(x,gamma), data))

print( name(['01100', '10101', '11001', '10101', '01', '010101010101010'], [1,0,1,0,1]) )
# ['10101', '10101']
```

I used two builtin functions to help me write `string_matches_intlist`:

- [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), to check that all elements of a sequence satisfy a property;
- [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), to iterate on two sequences simultaneously.